# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable?

Tags: python

```
li=[1,2,3,4,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,15,24,21,33,22] 
ll=list(filter(lambda x:(x%2 == 0),li))
print(ll)
```

and I'm getting this error

```
 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: The example you've posted works for me. Have you assigned something as `list` variable before? You can do `print(list)` to verify...

Comment: Though you can create variables with built-ins, it should be discouraged to avoid confusion in the code.

Comment: Please edit your first post if this code is a portion of whole. As @AndrejKesely mentioned, I did not get any errors either when running yours.

Comment: it seems like you used `list = ...` to assign value to variable `list` and now you can't use function `list()`